# Duplicate default WP REST API (v2) endpoints

Tags: wordpress, rest

How can i duplicate default wp rest api V2 endpoints? I would like to keep default endpoints and routs intact, but would like to use simplified responses for my application.

Wordpress v4.7

My code for now:

```
function register_custom_routes()
{
    $controller = new MY_REST_Posts_Controller;
    $controller->register_routes();
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_custom_routes', 1 );

class MY_REST_Posts_Controller extends WP_REST_Controller {
 // this is a copy of default class WP_REST_Posts_Controller
}
```

Calling `http://localhost/wp/wp-json/` list my namespace ( /myrest ), also 
`http://localhost/wp/wp-json/myrest/`gives me:

```
{
  "namespace": "myrest",
  "routes": {
    "/myrest": {
      "namespace": "myrest",
      "methods": [
        "GET"
      ],
    ...
    "/myrest/(?P<id>[\\d]+)": {
      "namespace": "myrest",
      "methods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "PATCH",
        "DELETE"
      ],
     ...
}
```

but when i try to list posts with `http://localhost/wp/wp-json/myrest/posts` (like with default api route call) it does not work:

```
{
  "code": "rest_no_route",
  "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
  "data": {
    "status": 404
  }
}
```

I need simplified version of get posts response for android app but also want to keep default rest endpoints and routs as is.

Comment: did you find any solutions? I'm looking for the same.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution. I've wrapped code in wp plugin.

```
class WP_REST_custom_controller extends WP_REST_Controller {

    // this is a copy of default class WP_REST_Posts_Controller


    // Edited constructor for cutom namespace and endpoint url
    /**
     * Constructor.
     *
     * @since 4.7.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param string $post_type Post type.
     */
    public function __construct() {

        $this->post_type = 'post';
        $this->namespace = 'custom_namespace/v1';
        $obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type );
        $this->rest_base = ! empty( $obj->rest_base ) ? $obj->rest_base : $obj->name;

        $this->resource_name = 'posts';

        $this->meta = new WP_REST_Post_Meta_Fields( $this->post_type );
    }


    // this is a copy of default class WP_REST_Posts_Controller with necessary edits

}

// Function to register our new routes from the controller.
function register_custom_rest_routes() {
    $controller = new WP_REST_custom_controller();
    $controller->register_routes();
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_custom_rest_routes');
```